# cannot use and object as a parameter to a method - on standard implementation

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview, primitive-types

```
-(NSString)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

when i try to implement this method, i get the error mentioned but that seems incorrect. i have 2 questions

isn't nsinteger a primitive type (not needing to be passed as a pointer)? 
why does the apple provided implementation lack the asterisk if i am supposed to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the return type, `NSString` (object) should be `NSString*` (pointer). The `NSInteger` is fine.